# Custom Header Autocompletion in TypeScript and Express.js with res.setHeader()

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, http

I'm working on a TypeScript project with Express.js and want to improve autocompletion and type support for custom headers when using the `res.setHeader()` method. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
import * as express from "express"

export function traceIdMiddleware(
    req: express.Request,
    res: express.Response,
    next: express.NextFunction
) {
    if (req.headers["X-Trace-ID"]) {
        const traceId = req.headers["X-Trace-ID"];
        res.setHeader("X-Trace-ID", traceId);
    }

    // more logic...
    next();
}
```

How can I extend the TypeScript Express interface to get autocompletion and type checking for custom headers like `X-Trace-ID` when using `res.setHeader()`?

I tried to extend Express.Response, but it didn't work.

```
declare global {
    namespace Express {
        interface Response {
            setHeader(field: 'X-Trace-ID', value: string): this;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`express.Response` is an extension of `http.ServerResponse`, which in turn extends `OutgoingMessage` class. Therefore, to enable autocomplete functionality, I simply needed to modify the `OutgoingMessage` like this:

```
declare module 'http' {
    interface OutgoingMessage {
        setHeader(name: "X-Trace-ID", value: string): this;
    }
}
```